# Find out the data update and data ingestion frequency of CiviCRM, phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, civicrm

Hi I'm using CiviCRM for membership management. The database is not set up by me and it's old. I wonder where can I find out the database update frequency. I access the database via phpMyAdmin.
I had a look on the information schema but didn't see anything useful.

thanks!

Comment: You may do better to ask here http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active

Answer (score 0):

if you mean code updates, which may impact db, civicrm.org/blog/tags/release

if you mean other minimum requirements (php and mysql) try here docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/general/requirements

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the version of CiviCRM installed, you can see it in the column `version` of the table `civicrm_domain` :

```
SELECT version FROM civicrm_domain;
```

Since CiviCRM 5+, there is exactly one release every month. As we are at 5.50, it's quite easy to know how old is your CiviCRM. Also see here for the list of releases : https://civicrm.org/blog/tags/release

CiviCRM is not a standard module / plugins, it's more of it's own software that can be integrated with the CMS (Drupal / WordPress). There is no auto update so you need to do it manually using this procedure depending on the CMS :

- https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/drupal7/
- https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/drupal8/
- https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/wordpress/
- https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/joomla/

Lastly, if you have more questions on your CiviCRM, there is a specific StackExchange here : https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/